# Problem on differential Calculus and Series by Joseph Edwards

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, logarithms

**This Question asks for the summation of the series below, through some use of derivatives and log**

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\theta^2 - (rπ)^2} = \frac{1}{\theta^2 - π^2} + \frac{1}{\theta^2 - 2^2π^2} +\frac{1}{\theta^2 - 3^2π^2} + .....\infty$$

Now , if you take the summation as **Y** then
$$ Y = \frac{1}{2π\theta}\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dr}\log\frac{\theta + rπ}{\theta - rπ}$$
But I can't get ahead after this, so I need help

Comment: This looks like a telescoping series.

Comment: That does not appear to be what you've been told to do. To "differentiate a function $f(x)$ logarithmically" is to find the ratio $f'(x)/f(x)$. You are supposed to find the logarithmic derivative of "the expression of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ in factors", not this series. What expression it is talking about, I do not know. Presumably, it is something that preceeds this question in your book.

Comment: Do you know the infinite product for $\sin x$ as $x\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$? And do you realize that the problem is obvious once you know the above product?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No I didn't knew about it and actually I am not seeing how it makes things easier as the product has a resemblenance of the question but the question asks for summation , So I not sure if it's obvious Or you can enlighten me.

Comment: Well you can take logs to convert product into sum and then differentiate it and see what happens.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah I see it now but still I don't know much about the infinite product still, I know the expansion and all but what is it, and isn't there any other method to solve this question

Comment: I don't think there is another easy method. But someone here may help you out. Stay hopeful.